# I believe I need a Left Outer Join with a SUM aggregrate in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, aggregate-functions

Ok, I hope I can explain this to get to the point and resolve my issue. For simplicity, I have a material transaction table that links to a material lot number table by transaction_id. The material lot number table links to a batch header table on a batch_number. The batch header table links to a batch steps table on batch_id.

For 90% of the data if the batch_steps.batch_id = batch_header.batch_id and material_transaction.transaction_qty = batch_steps.step_qty it returns a correct value.

For some of the data the batch_steps table has the transaction_qty as say 3000 but the material_transaction table has 3 records with quantities of 1000, 500, and 1500. What I am trying to accomplish is first do the record based on the individual records and then SUM the material_transactions.transaction_qty and compare to the batch_steps.transaction_qty and if that matches return the record.

But when I tried to do the Left Outer Join with a Sum function, I bombed. And I see simple discussions on how to do this with 2 tables, but can't wrap my head around tying the tables I need together just to get the correct records to SUM. Thanks for any help in advance.

Like I said, I was trying to keep it simple. Here is my code I have so far.

```
select 



 mp.organization_code "ORG"

  , mmt.organization_id
  , mtln.lot_number
  , mmt.transaction_quantity "QTY"
  , msi.segment1 "Item_ID"
  , mgd.description "Trans_Source"
  , mtln.grade_code "Lot_Trans_Grade"
  , mmt.SUBINVENTORY_CODE "Subinventory"
  , msi2.description "Location"
  , fu.description "User_Name"
  , mmt.transaction_id
  , mmt.last_update_date "Trans_Date"
  , oap.period_name
  , gbh.batch_id
  , substr(mtln.lot_number,instr(mtln.lot_number,'(',-1) + 1, instr(mtln.lot_number,')',-1) - instr(mtln.lot_number,'(',-1) - 1) "Batch"
  , substr(mtln.lot_number,0,instr(mtln.lot_number,'-')-1) "Heat"
  , gbh.attribute13 "Project_Material_Request"
  , case when gbs.attribute5 is null then 'No DDR' else gbs.attribute5 end "DDR"
  , mmt.transaction_reference
  , (case when gbs.attribute5 <> 'No DDR' then majd.major_deviation else 
      (case when substr(mmt.transaction_reference,2,1) = '-' then majd.major_deviation else 'No DDR' end) end) as "Major_Reason"
  , (case when gbs.attribute5 <> 'No DDR' then mind.minor_deviation else 
      (case when substr(mmt.transaction_reference,2,1) = '-' then mind.minor_deviation else 'No DDR' end) end) as "Minor_Reason"

from mtl_material_transactions mmt 

left outer join mtl_transaction_lot_numbers mtln on mmt.transaction_id = mtln.transaction_id
left outer join mtl_system_Items_b msi on mtln.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = msi.inventory_item_id and mtln.organization_id = msi.organization_id
left outer join mtl_parameters mp on mtln.organization_id = mp.organization_id
left outer join MTL_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS mgd on mmt.transaction_source_id = mgd.disposition_id
left outer join apps.fnd_user fu on mmt.LAST_UPDATED_BY = fu.USER_ID
left outer join apps.org_acct_periods oap on mmt.acct_period_id = oap.acct_period_id
left outer join gme_batch_header gbh on substr(mtln.lot_number,instr(mtln.lot_number,'(',-1) + 1, instr(mtln.lot_number,')',-1) - instr(mtln.lot_number,'(',-1) - 1) = gbh.batch_no and substr(mtln.lot_number,0,instr(mtln.lot_number,'-')-1) = gbh.attribute12
left outer join gme_batch_steps gbs on mmt.transaction_quantity = -gbs.actual_step_qty and gbh.batch_id = gbs.batch_id and gbs.attribute5 > '0'
left outer join bolinf.xxalv_qa_ncr xqn on gbs.attribute5 = xqn.ncr_no
left outer join bolinf.xxalv_qa_major_deviations majd on xqn.major_deviation = majd.major_code or majd.major_code = substr(mmt.transaction_reference,1,1)
left outer join bolinf.xxalv_qa_minor_deviations mind on (xqn.minor_deviation = mind.minor_code and majd.deviation_id = mind.deviation_id) or (substr(mmt.transaction_reference,3,2) = mind.minor_code and majd.deviation_id = mind.deviation_id)
left outer join mtl_secondary_inventories msi2 on msi2.organization_id = mp.organization_id and mmt.subinventory_code = msi2.secondary_inventory_Name

where 
  mgd.description = 'Scrapped Lot'
  and 
  oap.period_name like '%May-15%'

  ORDER BY mmt.transaction_id
```

This is the piece that works as long as the quantities match, but once this condition is met I then want it to look at summing the quantities of the mmt.transaction_quantity and validate if it matches the -gbs.actual_step_qty and if so grab the gbs.attribute5:

```
left outer join gme_batch_steps gbs on mmt.transaction_quantity = -gbs.actual_step_qty and gbh.batch_id = gbs.batch_id and gbs.attribute5 > '0'

case when gbs.attribute5 is null then 'No DDR' else gbs.attribute5 end "DDR"
```

Here is a sample of the data I am getting:
These records are what I am trying to combine the QTY to validate against the Batch Steps table:

```
ORG  LOT_NUMBER                  QTY      Item_ID     TRANSACTION_ID  BATCH_ID  Batch  DDR     Major_Reason  Minor_Reason
---  --------------------------  -------  ----------  --------------  --------  -----  ------  ------------  ------------
OPS  M4A18-1-T-1 SCRAP-(49326)   (1,310)  BLT1001511  11334584        120250    49326  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4A18-1-T-2 SCRAP-(49326)   (251)    BLT1001511  11334585        120250    49326  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-3(SCRAP)-(50135)  (626)    BLT1001630  10961459        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-7(SCRAP)-(50135)  (636)    BLT1001630  10961461        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-8(SCRAP)-(50135)  (602)    BLT1001630  10961462        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-6(SCRAP)-(50135)  (638)    BLT1001630  10961463        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-5(SCRAP)-(50135)  (596)    BLT1001630  10961464        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-2(SCRAP)-(50135)  (623)    BLT1001630  10961465        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-4(SCRAP)-(50135)  (630)    BLT1001630  10961467        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-T-1(SCRAP)-(50135)  (622)    BLT1001630  10961468        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
OPS  M4C44-3-B-9(SCRAP)-(50135)  (591)    BLT1001630  10961469        123338    50135  No DDR  No DDR        No DDR
```

These 2 records meet the condition as written:

```
ORG  LOT_NUMBER              QTY   Item_ID     TRANSACTION_ID  BATCH_ID  Batch  DDR    Major_Reason   Minor_Reason
---  ----------------------  ----  ----------  --------------  --------  -----  -----  -------------  ------------
OPS  C4C63-6-SCRAP-(62759)   (60)  BAR1001495  11139269        168373    62759  47563  SONIC DEFECTS  GRAIN STRUCTURE
OPS  C4C63-6-SCRAP#-(62759)  (48)  BAR1001495  11161614        168373    62759  48002  DIMENSIONAL    TOL. OUTSIDE DRAWING
```

Hope this helps clear up any issues with what I originally stated. Thanks.

Comment: So with no details of your query and no details of the error you're getting, you expect people to diagnose your issue? Mmmmmmkay.

Comment: I suggest you do some sqlfiddle.com and show us your work first.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I understand, you need to sum the quantities first in a construct like this:

`WITH mts as (SELECT id, SUM(transaction_qty)transaction_qty 
               FROM material_transaction 
               GROUP BY id)
SELECT *
  FROM batch_header bh, batch_steps bs, mts 
 WHERE bs.batch_id = bh.batch_id
   AND mts.transaction_qty = batch_steps.step_qty;`

should do the trick since now, the equality on sums should work.

WITH construct allow to create a local view that you can reuse in the subsequent SELECT as many times as you want.

I let you test this and tell me if it is OK or not.

Regards,

Christian

Comment: Thank you Christian! It has got me going in the right direction. I am having some issues now with duplicate records but working through that.

Comment: Glad it helps you... could you just push the up button?